# MetaClass not intercepting protected method

Tags: groovy

I'm testing a runtime change in the groovy.sql.Sql MetaClass, modifying the createConnection method. My aim is to allways call a process when some connection is requested.

Is there a restriction for changing protected methods? I can see that my change don't have effect, and if I log the `invokeMethod()`, only public methods are printed.

Maybe I'm incorrect in my approach? Here's my script:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='com.h2database', module='h2', version='1.3.160'),
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
])
import com.h2database.*
import groovy.sql.*
import java.sql.*

def originalMethod = Sql.metaClass.&createConnection

Connection.metaClass.createConnection = { 
  println "Called $name"
  originalMethod.invoke(this)
}

def db = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:h2:mem:', 'sa', '', 'org.h2.Driver')

// Setup database.
db.execute '''
    create table if not exists languages(
        id int primary key,
        name varchar(20) not null
    )
'''
```

Comment: What is the actual implementation? And how is the `MethodClosure` `originalMethod` used?

Comment: The originalMethod is used to return the `Connection` applying the original logic of `groovy.sql.Sql`. By "actual implementation" you mean the Sql class impl, or my createConnection substitution?

Comment: Your substitution. Basically the whole script as a workable sample show casing the problem, if feasible.

Comment: Just a heads up, a method pointer is created on the Class or on the instance instead of a metaClass. So use `def originalMethod = Sql.&createConnection` to start with. The way you have now, with my suggested change you would get a StackOverflow because of recursive calls to `createConnection`, so adding the full use case would help figure out the actual issue, I hope.

Comment: @dmahapatro Ok, edited with an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here isn't related to protected methods.  The issue is that you are using Groovy's runtime metapgrogramming to replace an existing method and then expecting that meta programming to be in play when the method in question is called from Java.  This style of metaprogramming doesn't apply to method calls made directly from Java.  The groovy.sql.Sql class is written in Java and as such when the code inside of groovy.sql.Sql invokes the createConnection method, the real method is used, not the one that was metaprogrammed.